# What is voice xml and how can I host it

Tags: xml, host, protocol, voice

while looking for a way to use speech recognition with flash I crossed paths with voice xml. I've gone through the wc3 description of it but still I have a few big questions.

Can I simply create a vxml doc and place it on my webserver? What are the requirements?

Will it work?

Can I input with a microphone over the internet?

I can't seem to find a direct answer to it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

VoiceXML is just a control structure for IVR's (and possibly other applications, but i have never seen it used outside of IVR's). It allows you to standardize your prompts, playback, call flow, etc. VXML isn't really designed for what you are looking to do with it. It was developed for IVR applications.

To answer you questions:

1- No.
1a - You would need to find a VXML server or plugin to your server that would integrate with flash, and allow for proper interpretation of the VXML - I don't believe such a thing exists
2. Possibly
3. If you can find the right back end software It would be input agnostic, although the quality you would get off the internet would not be consistent.

Comment: Thank you for the clear up. Is there any free program I can use with speech recognition that would be easy to get the words out of it?

For example I say "hello" and the program outputs to flash "hello" or passes it as a variable to php?

Comment: @Logodym: Not that I'm aware of, Flash might have some way to capture audio, but I don't know the tech well enough to be of any help there.

Comment: Great answer. I did some work with VXML back in '05 - it's very powerful stuff, but the guy who I was working with had it as a major in his degree, so you need to really study it to do it properly